# I uploaded a laravel project in cPanel and I'm getting this error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

> Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'tfs_user'@'localhost' to database 'tfs' (SQL: select * from `settings`)

When i click login/registration page i'm getting this error. i can't understand what's the problem. I updated my .env file with correct database info.

.env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=tfs
DB_USERNAME=tfs_user
DB_PASSWORD=tfsdemo01
```

database.php file

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',<
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

How can i solve this error, can anyone help me please.

Comment: `php artisan config:cache` fire this command on `CMD`

Comment: GRANT ALL access to `tfs_user` user

Comment: yes. @RiggsFolly i created the user with password.

Comment: GRANT ALL access to tfs_user user,  where should i put this command @devpro

Comment: php artisan config:cache How can i run this command in cPanel @DrakulaPredator

Comment: first of all check either it set or not, if not then run this `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON tfs.* TO 'tfs_user'@'localhost';` in your phpmyadmin

Comment: How to run this in cPanel @devpro

Comment: @AminHossain: open your cpanel >> find PHP my admin >> after open it, select database >> goto SQL tab >> and place this query >> and press Go button at bottom :p

Comment: @devpro i checked and found that i already gave all the PRIVILEGES to this user. But still its showing same error.

Comment: @AminHossain: change the password

Comment: @devpro changed and checked still same. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the mysql server is on the same server as your application use host as localhost

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

Comment: Its normally faster to use `127.0.0.1` but basically this should make no difference

Comment: @RiggsFolly
mysql treat 'localhost' as UNIX socket, 127.0.0.1 will only work if mysql-proxy is setup and run it on 127.0.0.1